# Prime factor inversion

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, fixed-points

Define a function $f(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to "invert" the prime
factorization of $n$ in the following sense. Let me start with an example.

If $n= 3564 = 2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 11^1$,
then $f(n) = 2^2 \cdot 4^3 \cdot 1^{11} = 256$,
inverting the base primes and their exponents.

In general, if the prime
factorization of $n$ is $p_1^{m_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot p_k^{m_k}$,
then $f(n) = m_1^{p_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot m_k^{p_k}$.

Continuing the above example:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(n) &= f(3564 = 2^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 11^1) & = 2^2 \cdot 4^3 \cdot 1^{11} = 256\\
f^2(n)&=f(256=2^8) &= 8^2 =64 \\
f^3(n)&=f(64 = 2^6) &= 6^2 = 36 \\
f^4(n)&=f(36 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2) &= 2^2 \cdot 2^3 = 32\\
f^5(n)&=f(32 = 2^5) &= 5^2 = 25\\
f^6(n)&=f(25 = 5^2) &= 2^5 = 32
\end{eqnarray}
and we have fallen into a $2$-cycle. My questions concern the iterated behavior of $f(n)$.

- **Q1**. If $n= \Pi p_i$, $p_i$ primes, then $f(n) = 1$.
  If $n= \Pi p_i^{p_i}$, $p_i$ primes, then $f(n) = n$, a fixed point.
  Are any other $n$ fixed points or $n$ that eventually lead to $1$-cycles?
- **Q2**. If $n= \Pi p_i^{q_i} \cdot q_j^{p_j}$, all of $p_i,p_j,q_i,q_j$ primes, then $f^2(n)=n$, a $2$-cycle.
  Can you see a characterization of those $n$ that eventually fall into a $2$-cycle?
- **Q3**. Are there any $n$ that eventually fall into $k$-cycles
  for $k \ge 3$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is [OEIS sequence A008477](https://oeis.org/A008477), where I find the comment

> For any n, the sequence n, a(n), a(a(n)), a(a(a(n))), ... is eventually periodic with period <= 2 [Farrokhi]. - N. J. A. Sloane, Apr 25 2009

The reference is to

M. Farrokhi, [The Prime Exponentiation of an Integer: Problem 11315](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40391138), Amer. Math. Monthly, 116 (2009), 470.

Comment: Good find, Robert! Hard to be original with such a natural question.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Yes, for example $p^q q^p$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, is a fixed point (or products that consist of these). More generally you should be able to use permutations of order $2$, i.e products of disjoint transpositions.

Comment: 16 is a fixed point also, because $2^4 = 4^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't think so - $f(2^3 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^2) = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot  5^3 \neq 2^3 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Numbers of that form will have the same period as the order of $\sigma$ under iteration of $f$.